# What weapons do I need to leave?

Tags: fallout-4

There is a certain point in the Railroad quest Underground Undercover where I have an optional item to leave weapons in a locker.  I went back to my workbench and grabbed a handful of guns and dropped them off, but it did not mark the quest item as complete.

Anybody have an idea as to either the count or style of guns that need to be left?

Comment: If you walk into a court with an ak-47 and the security asks you to leave all your weapons with them, would you run home, get a few more, leave those and walk into the court with the ak?

Comment: I'm trying to think which quest this is, and I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: This is about the Underground undercover quest, when you need to put weapons in a locker to supply the synth rebels.

Answer (score 3):

The [Underground Undercover page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Underground_Undercover) on Nukapedia says that

> The optional "deposit weapons" objective is completed when a certain number of weapons have been placed in the marked locker. Placing a stack of weapons appears to only count once, so put them in the crate one at a time. (see talk page for speculation)

I took a look at the speculation on the talk page, and it seems people are getting varying results. Taking it all in, it looks to me like you need to put in 10 weapons, but that putting those weapons in is buggy and error-prone. The last comment at the time of writing this seems like it is probably the best advice:

> Putting them in one at a time and closing the container between each seems to be the trick. With that method, I had it completed after 10.

Comment: I will check this out the next time I'm at the institute and report back.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need a certain amount of weapons before the quest will be marked as complete. I remember I had to put in at least 10-20 guns before the quest marker disappeared. I had guns of many types too, several regular handguns (pipe, 10mm and some syndicate stuff) I don't think there is a specific type required. 
It's entirely optional though, I believe it'll only make the rebels fighting with you have better gear, but I'm not certain.